# I'd like to upgrade to Laravel 5.5 from Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, upgrade

I'm using Laravel 4.2. I have checked Laravel document about upgrading.(https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade)

But, my question is, does Upgrading have to be done step by step?

For Example, 
Ver 4.2 ⇒ 5.0 ⇒ 5.1 ⇒ 5.2 ⇒ 5.3 ⇒ 5.4 ⇒ 5.5

Or, Can it directly upgrade to Laravel 5.5 From 4.2?

Comment: Have a look into LaravelShift, tiny cost for automated upgrade

Answer (score 0):

In your case  going from 4.2 to 5.5 may be  a bit hard .

Considering that the  major breakpoints of laravel are laravel 5.0 and laravel 5.4  you should split the process in 2 steps .
1)Going from 4.2->5.0 means a big refactor on laravel's controller and ORM.
2) 5->5.5  comes up with new laravel features  that helps you re-organize your code  or provides new stuff . 
So either you should make an initial reform and then look for laravels 5++ features or you should start the project from scratch

Answer (score -1):

You can upgrade files directly to the latest version anytime, that can be done with any software.

However between major versions there are backwards compatibility breaking changes that surely will affect your code so you must follow upgrade notes for every version. And because Laravel does not adhere to the standard called [SemVer](https://semver.org/), there's a lot of work ahead of you, because there are BC breaking changes in the minor versions as well.

For instance, if SemVer was respected (like in Symfony, Zend Framework, etc.) you would only need to read one upgrade note (from v4 to v5).